# How to workaround CSS page-break-inside: avoid; failing to avoid break?

Tags: html, css, printing

I am trying to have the contents of a web page print onto one page of paper.
But, it is breaking the content into 2 pages, so I did some research here and see people recommending:

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">

#my_print_div{
width:940px;
height:770px;
page-break-after: always; /* Always insert page break after this element */
page-break-inside: avoid; /* Please don't break my page content up browser */
}

</style>

<div id='my_print_div'> My content to be printed here</div>
```

My `div` still breaks and then carries on to the next page to print - UNLESS I select "Shrink to Fit" - in Mozilla Firefox.

- **Is there a way to make sure the content of a DIV DOES NOT print on 2
  pages? I want to force the content to 1 printable page**
- **Is there a known pixel width height to match landscape 11 inch by 8.5 inch Letter size
  paper?**

Thank you

Comment: 72pts in an inch. On a mac, 72pts = 72px. A Windows uses 96 pixesl in an inch. I've never used those page-break-after: always; amazing that it would add the appropriate universal character!

Comment: Thanks @kelly johnson - So on a Mac, 792px DIV - would give you your 10 inches of print paper? And 612px gives you your 8.5 inches of paper?

Answer (score 6):

The point of the `page-break` properties is not to shrink content to fit on a page, but to help decide the optimal place for a page break to occur.

So, if you use `page-break-inside:avoid` on an element, and there's not enough space on the current page to fit the entire element, the browser will consider inserting a break so as to force the element onto a new page, theoretically giving it more space.

However, if the element is so big that moving it onto a new page won't help, then there's nothing to be done (in terms of page breaks at least).

If you know in advance that your content will need to be shrunk when printing, you could try adding a scale transform on the problem elements (restricted to the print media type), so that they're a more manageable size.

Comment: It's also possible to workaround browser implementations with JS to some degree. For details, see https://www.pagedjs.org/documentation/cheatsheet/